# how can i fix "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout"?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have problem "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout". I think ScheduleListAdapter in this line.

`public int getItemCount() { return list.size(); }`

so i add this line in same page

`public ScheduleListAdapter(){ list = new ArrayList<>(); }`

but this error does not solved.

**MyFragment.Java**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private FragmentMyBinding binding;
    private Button goroutinesetbtn;
    private View view;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ScheduleListAdapter adapter = new ScheduleListAdapter();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my,container,false);

        MyViewModel homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        goroutinesetbtn =  view.findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
        binding = FragmentMyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
        MyViewModel.getSchedule().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),schedules ->{
            adapter.setScheduleList(schedules);
                }
        );

        goroutinesetbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RoutineSettingActivity.class); //fragment라서 activity intent와는 다른 방식
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

}
```

**ScheduleListAdapter.java**

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ScheduleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_schedule,parent,false);
    return new ScheduleViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ScheduleViewHolder holder, int position) {
 holder.setSchedule(list.get(position));
}

public ScheduleListAdapter(){
    list = new ArrayList\<\>();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

void setScheduleList(ArrayList\<Schedule\> list){
    this.list = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class ScheduleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
 ListScheduleBinding listScheduleBinding;
    public ScheduleViewHolder(@NonNull View scheduleView) {
        super(scheduleView);
        listScheduleBinding=ListScheduleBinding.bind(scheduleView);
    }
    public void setSchedule(Schedule schedule){
        listScheduleBinding.tvtitle.setText(schedule.getTitle());
        listScheduleBinding.tvcolor.setText(schedule.getColor());
        listScheduleBinding.tvstart.setText(schedule.getStart());
        listScheduleBinding.tvend.setText(schedule.getLast());
    }
}
}
```

**Schedule.Java**

```
public class Schedule {
    private String title;
    private String start;
    private String last;
    private String color;

    public Schedule(){}

    public String getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public String getColor() {return color;}

    public String getTitle() {return title;}

    public void setStart(String start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public void setLast(String last) {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {this.color = color;}

    public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}


    public Schedule(String title, String start, String last, String color){
        this.title = title;
        this.start = start;
        this.last = last;
        this.color = color;
        }

}
```

In ScheduleListAdapter, i know this "getItemCount()" have problem. so, i add ScheduleListAdapter. But this problem don't solve. How can i fix it????

```
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}


  public ScheduleListAdapter(){
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

**fragment_my.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.my.MyFragment">
<android.widget.Button
    android:id="@+id/addbtn"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:text="+"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.845"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.817" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="629dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the layout XML file `fragment_my.xml`